# How to extract several text lines between 2 h2 tags in XPath?

Tags: xpath

I tried to look everywhere here but it seems I can't figure out why my output doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
<h2> Title1 </h2>
"
Text 1"
<br>
"
Text 2"
<br>
"
Text 3
"
<h2> Title2 </h2>
```

I want to extract Text 1 Text 2 Text 3 but with the following Xpath, it doesn't work...

```
text()[preceding-sibling::h2[normalize-space()='Title1']]
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't use XPath for html, use jsoup. html is a nasty creature, full of pain and torment for the xpather.

Comment: btw, h2 is not a sibling of the text it is its parent.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use

```
//h2[normalize-space(text())="Title1"]/following-sibling::text()[position()<4]
```

but it can be applicable only for currently provided `HTML` sample: if there could be more or less `<br>"TextN"` parts - it won't match expected text content...

Comment: nope the result is the same as mine, just Text1 will appear

Comment: this might be because your simplified `html` sample structure is differs from original one

Answer (score 0):

**This is one possible way :**

```
//h2[normalize-space() = 'Title1']
 /following-sibling::text()[
    following-sibling::h2[1][normalize-space() = 'Title2']
 ]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/a5fcc4cda5b313c47cd95ff97ccfcb02)</kbd>**

**brief explanation :**

- **`//h2[normalize-space() = 'Title1']`**: Find `h1` elements where text content, after [whitespaces normalization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space), equals 'Title1'
- **`/following-sibling::text()`**: from such `h1` element, find all following sibling text nodes ...
- **`following-sibling::h2[1][normalize-space() = 'Title2']`**: ... where *nearest* following sibling `h2` content equals 'Title2'

Comment: thanks for your comment har07 but it doesn't work either... it just shows Text1 instead of all the Texts.